# Fit data with copula in R

Tags: r, copula

I have two data which are clearly related (according to Spearman and Kendall test); I would like to fit a copula using R but so far i wasn't able to find the best one.

[image: The data scatter looks like this one]

I tried all the evCopula and the Archimedean ones but the Goodness of fit test tell me they don't work. 
Could you advice me what else should I try according to plot and eventually how to do that in R ?